# Firefox add-on sdk uninstall hook

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I keep some user data in `simple-storage`. When the user uninstalls the add-on I want to remove this user data. Is there some event or something similar?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will work in every file:

```
require("sdk/system/unload").when(function(reason) {
  if (reason == "uninstall") {
    // do uninstall stuff..
  }
});
```

Comment: Strange, but in my case I've got the 'disable' reason, when I click remove addon. But in any case, thanks for solution.

Comment: You always got 'disable' due to bug in API, see comment on it in the bottom of the page: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Tutorials/Listening_for_load_and_unload

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
exports.onUnload = function(reason) {
   //do stuff for unload here
}
```

Comment: I think this only works in the main.js file, and it's deprecated.